# edit html page and redisplay PHP

Tags: php, screen-scraping

So I have been using a method to retrieve images from a website but I thought it may be easier to simply show the page without some details I don't want displayed. The website in paticular know we are doing this so there shouldn't be any legal complications. So would it be possible to open the html page within PHP, search for a specific  that would be the same in each page, remove it and then redisplay the page within the browser with its new edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) or [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/) libraries to clean up and navigate the document tree, find the elements you are looking for, and remove them. I can't find comprehensive docs for Tidy, but the examples on php.net should be enough to help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, you'd need to use [`file_get_contents("http://url");`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to load the page into a string, then [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a regex to clean the string.